# Pandas column computation - Recursion Error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing CSV data as follows:

> time  animal_id       x       y
>
> 0     1        120  205.29  217.76
>
> 1     1        100  169.99  128.78
>
> 2     1        200  590.33  505.89
>
> 3     1        300  645.15  611.94
>
> 4     1        350  866.06  851.76

The dimensions of the file are 216005 rows and 4 attributes/columns.

I have grouped the file according to 'animal_id' and afterwards have added some additional attributes which I have to compute (viz., distance, average_speed, average_acceleration, positive_acceleration, direction).

The code for this is:

```
# Apply grouping using 'animal_id' attribute-
data_animal_id = data.groupby('animal_id')

# A dictionary object to hold all groups obtained using group by-
data_animal_id_groups = {}


# Get each animal_id's data from grouping performed-
for animal_id in data_animal_id.groups.keys():
    data_animal_id_groups[animal_id] = data_animal_id.get_group(animal_id)

# To reset index for each group-
for animal_id in data_animal_id_groups.keys():
    data_animal_id_groups[animal_id].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


# Add additional attributes/columns to each groups-
for aid in data_animal_id_groups.keys():
    data = [0 for x in range(data_animal_id_groups[aid].shape[0])]

    data_animal_id_groups[aid] = data_animal_id_groups[aid].assign(distance=data)
    data_animal_id_groups[aid] = data_animal_id_groups[aid].assign(average_speed=data)
    data_animal_id_groups[aid] = data_animal_id_groups[aid].assign(average_acceleration=data)
    data_animal_id_groups[aid] = data_animal_id_groups[aid].assign(positive_acceleration=data)
    data_animal_id_groups[aid] = data_animal_id_groups[aid].assign(direction=data)
```

I am now, trying to compute the direction using the following logic:

```
for aid in data_animal_id_groups.keys():
    print("\nComputing Distance & Direction for Animal ID = {0}\n".format(aid))
    for i in range(1, data_animal_id_groups[aid].shape[0] - 1):     

        x1 = data_animal_id_groups[aid].iloc[i, 2]
        y1 = data_animal_id_groups[aid].iloc[i, 3]
        x2 = data_animal_id_groups[aid].iloc[i + 1, 2]
        y2 = data_animal_id_groups[aid].iloc[i + 1, 3]

        # Compute distance between 2 points-
        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + math.pow((y2 - y1), 2))

        # Compute the direction in DEGREES-
        direction = math.degrees(math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)))

        if math.isnan(direction):
            data_animal_id_groups[aid].loc[i, 'Direction'] = 0
            # animal_id.loc[i, 'Direction'] = 0
        else:
            data_animal_id_groups[aid].loc[i, 'Direction'] = direction
```

However, this takes a long time to compute. So, I was trying to use the following numpy code:

```
direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan((data_animal_id_groups[312]['y'] - data_animal_id_groups[312]['y'].shift(periods = 1, axis = 0)), (data_animal_id_groups[312]['x'] - data_animal_id_groups[312]['x'].shift(periods = 1, axis = 0))))
```

But, this gives the error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a
>   Python object

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: There are other ways of speeding up that computation. You generally don't want to iterate over a dataframe - it's much better to use something like `apply`.